# Kubernetes Prometheus and OpenMetrics metrics collection

Tags: kotlin, logging, prometheus, integration, datadog

I have a kotlin application which was sending custom metrics to datadog. After changing the structure to multi-module the data is not being sent any longer, can anyone please help me here? I have tried verifying the details there has been no change to datadog metric collection logic.